# Printing a nested data structure in Clojure

Tags: formatting, clojure

I wrote the following code which transforms a nested data structure

```clj
(def board [[{:mine true}             {:warn 1 :explored true} {:explored true}]
           [{:warn 1 :explored true}  {:warn 1 :explored true} {}              ]
           [{}                        {}                       {:flag true }   ]])
```

into a printable form and prints it

```clj
(("[ ]" "[1]" "[E]") ("[1]" "[1]" "[ ]") ("[ ]" "[ ]" "[F]"))
```

The functions for the transformation are the following:

```clj
(defn cell->icon 
  [cell]
  (letfn [(cell->str [v] (format "[%s]" v))]  
    (if (:explored cell) 
      (cond (:mine cell) (cell->str "M")
            (:warn cell) (cell->str (:warn cell))
            :else        (cell->str "E"))
      (cond (:flag cell) (cell->str "F")
            :else        (cell->str " ")))))

(defn board->icons
  [board]
  (map (partial map cell->icon) board))
```

So far so good (if you have any recommendations for a nicer approach though, do not hesitate to mention).

The function which I don't like though is the following:

```clj
(defn print-board
  [board]
  (doall 
    (map println
       (map (partial clojure.string/join " ")
            (board->icons board)))))
```

I don't like to use `println` together with map since it is not a pure function (has side-effects)!? Maybe I am a bit too critical but I would be glad if somebody could advice me or give a hint how to do it in a nicer Clojure like way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Separate impure IO from data transformations

> I wrote the following code which transforms a nested data structure ... into a printable form

Not only does your code transform the data into a printable form, it also prints it.

To better isolate the side effects of printing, you should separate these two operations: first assemble a formatted string, then you can do whatever you want with it -- print it with a single call to `println`, save it, send it over the network, etc.

```clj
(defn format-board
  [board]
  (->> (board->icons board)
       (map (partial str/join " "))
       (str/join "\n")))

(def print-board
  (comp println format-board))
```

---

### [`doseq`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/doseq)

As a side note, instead of `(doall (map println seq-to-print))` it is common to see

```clj
(doseq [line seq-to-print]
  (println line))
```

which is usually what you want, since

- `doseq` does not hold onto the return value of `println`, whereas `doall` builds up an entire return sequence in memory (important when the sequence is big!) -- which is why your original `print-board` returns `(nil nil nil)` instead of `nil`; and
- this makes it more visually clear that you are *doing* something with each item in the sequence, instead of generating a new sequence with `map`